# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate not working. {new: true} included

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I tried to edit the info and update it, but the mongoose findByIdAndUpdate didn't work. The {new: true} is included, but it still shows the original one. In the database, the info is not updated either. The console shows PUT /blogs/:id  302.

The routes are as follows:

```
//edit
router.get('/blogs/:id/edit', function (req, res) {
    Blog.findById(req.params.id, function (err, blogFound) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render("edit", {blog: blogFound});
        }
    });
});

//update
router.put('/blogs/:id', function (req, res) {
    Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.blog, {new: true},function (err, blogUpdated) {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else{
           res.redirect('/blogs/' + req.params.id);
       }
    });
});
```

The edit form looks like this:

```
<form class="ui form" action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<%= blog.title %>">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Image</label>
            <input type="text" name="image" value="<%= blog.image %>">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea name="description"><%= blog.description %></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="ui primary button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It happens if you insert a new document and then change it. If you get the new document first and then change it the update will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems `req.body.blog` is undefined.

you have title, image and description in your body not grouped in `blog` object, so you shall write

```
const { title, image, description } = req.body;
Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { title, image, description },
```

or smth like this

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I've been trapped in this for hours.